# How to conditionally execute code if a variable is NOT null in one line of code in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, boolean

In Dart, how do we do an operation only if a variable is NOT null... and accomplish that in one line?

Example:

```
void main() {
  
  int? i; // pretend we don't know if it's null or not
  
  // the laborious way:
  if (i == null) {
    print("the variable is null");
  }
  
  // the one-line way:
  i ?? print("the variable is null");
  
  // the laborious way:
  if (i != null) {
    print("the variable is not null");
  }
  
  // the one-line way:
   
  // i <what opertaor goes here?> print("the variable is null")
  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you remove body params'{}' it is single line.

```dart
 if (i == null) print("if (i == null), the variable is not null");
```

Also you can do something with ternary. but seems having extra null.

```dart
i == null ? print("i==null, the variable is not null") : null;
```

---

You can use this extension , you can return bool based on your need.

```dart
extension NullChecker<T> on T? {
  get isNull => print("This variable is ${this != null ? "not" : ""} null");
}
```

And use,

```dart
void main() {
  int? i = 4, j;
  i.isNull; //This variable is not null
  j.isNull; //This variable is  null
}
```